# Syncing local copy after subversion migration

Tags: svn, version-control

I recently migrated a subversion repository to a new server and I have a question about the following scenario:

1) Pre-migration:
Local copy A was checked out from subversion server A.

2) Subversion server A was migrated to subversion server B.
There are local changes in local copy A that weren't checked in prior to the migration.

3) Post migration:
Is there a way for me to sync up local copy A with the new subversion server B?
Or do I need to re-checkout from B and merge the local copies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you have to grab checkout from B, copy the modifications and merge.
Also think that it's not a good idea to keep both servers. 
To have diferent servers may be a better choice to use a diferent product than SVN.

Answer (score 1):

You may try "svn relocate" to change working copy URL to the target repository. And then commit your changes.